# Exibir localizações buscando pelo endereço no arquivo JSON / Google Maps Api

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Olá, estou com a necessidade de fazer uma busca no arquivo json, onde os atributos que irá me retornar a localização seria endereço(Rua, Número, Bairro, Cidade) e com essas informações em mãos o javascript precisaria converter para latitude e longitude para exibir no mapa.

o trecho de código onde tento fazer isso funcionar:

```js
function carregaEnderecos() {
    $.getJSON('Scripts/pontos.json', function (pontos) {
        $.each(pontos, function (index, ponto) {
            var addressInput = document.getElementById(ponto).value;

            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


            geocoder.geocode({ address: addressInput }, function (results, status) {

                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                    var myResult = results[0].geocoder.location;

                    createMarker(myResult);

                    title: 'Ponto';
                    icon: 'Images/location.png';
                    map.setCenter(myResult);
                    center: map;
                    map.setZoom(17);
                }

                infoBox[ponto.Id] = new InfoBox(myOptions);
                infoBox[ponto.Id].marker = marker;

                infoBox[ponto.Id].listener = google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (e) {
                    abrirInfoBox(ponto.Id, marker);
                });

                latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: O que `console.log(results[0].geocoder)` retorna?

Comment: Marconi, Retorna nulo

Comment: Você habilitou as APIS no console de desenvolver corretamente?

Comment: Sim, está habilitado